# How to assign values to a struct type variable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

So my compiler is complaining about my destination.travelTime having 3 arguments although it should have 3 arguments, any suggestions on how to fix this or am I in the wrong? TIA

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct timeType
{
    int hr;
    double min;
    int sec;
};

struct tourType
{
    string cityName;
    int distance;
    timeType travelTime;
};


int main()
{
    tourType destination;

    destination.cityName = "Nottingham";
    destination.distance = 130;
    destination.travelTime (3, 15.0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: do `tourType destination { "Nottingham", 130, {3, 15.0, 0} };`

Comment: See also [Struct and union initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization)

Answer (score 2):

`destination.travelTime (3, 15.0, 0);` is a function call, not an assignment. You would need to do this instead:

```
destination.travelTime = timeType{3, 15.0, 0};
```

Or

```
destination.travelTime = {3, 15.0, 0};
```

Depending on your C++ version.

Comment: yes, the question has already been asked thanks for your time guys :)